# Non-static data member initializers only available with and dynamic memory

Tags: c++

i have 2 problems.

First:

***warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11***

Second:

### How convert this code to code with dynamic memory?

```
#include iostream
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include time.h

using namespace std;

#define MAX 20

class tStack{    
    int STACK[MAX];
    int sizee=0;
    public:
    bool empty(){
        return sizee==0;
    }
    int val(){
        if (sizee==0) throw "Stack is empty";
        return STACK[sizee];
    }
    int pop(){
        if (sizee==0) throw "Stack is empty";
        return STACK[sizee--];
    }
    void push(int co){
        if (sizee==MAX-1) throw "Stack is full";
        sizee++;
        STACK[sizee]=co;
    }
    void writeTop(){
        cout<<val()<<endl;
    }};

int main(){    
    tStack stack;
    try{
        stack.push(4);
        stack.push(8);
        stack.push(5);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<stack.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<stack.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<stack.pop()<<endl;
        cout<<stack.pop()<<endl;
    }catch (const char *msg){
        cout<<"exception: "<<msg<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamic memory? The compiler tells you that `int sizee=0;` (default value for member variables) is a C++11 feature

Comment: just how to edit to make dynamic memory

Comment: What have you tried doing? SO is not a free code writing service, you need to show your attempt and explain what problem you are having with it. As is there is no attempt at using dynamically allocated memory

Answer (score 1):

> How convert this code to code with dynamic memory?

I guess what you mean is to replace the fixed size array `int STACK[MAX];` with a dynamic container.

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> stack
```

The rest you should figure it out for yourself.

Also the C++ standard library also has a stack container adapter, but I assume you need to create your own for educational purposes.

Answer (score -1):

For warning you can check the -std=c++11 flag in codeblocks following : Settings -> Compiler and check the  `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard` option.

For dynamic memory, you must use malloc/calloc or new to allocate memory. Make a struct for your stack, something like `struct elem { int info, struct elem *previous};` And when you must push something allocate memory for the new element, add value to stack and link the last value to new one.

`newElem = new elem;
 elem -> info = info;
 elem -> previous = topOfTheStack;`

Now, 
`topofTheStack` is `newElem`, 
so `topOfTheStack = newElem`;

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot encourage the use of raw new/delete in C++. Use standard containers. Or at least smart pointers. Or if you really really insist of using raw/delete you should follow the principles of RAII, single responsibility and the rule or 3/5. But then you just implement a smart pointer so ....

Comment: Why downvote? It's obvious that you can use standard containers, but I think he wanted to implement stack for himself by scratch.

Comment: I gave my reasons.